# ThingsBoard Where can i find out any details about entityGroupService or attributeService?

Tags: javascript, thingsboard

Personally i feel like the documentation is not nearly as good as it should be, theres so much functionality in widgets, or custom actions and the api sections aren't covered enough. I've been going crazy trying to find more documentation on attributeservice, or entitygroupservice to see what parameters it takes for what functions.

checked documentation, read through source code

Answer (score 2):

The way to go here, different that a proper TB PE support, is to look into the few examples in the platforms' UI, the codebase of the project and the swagger API specification.

You can find the most of those examples while creating a ['custom action' and a 'custom action with template'](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/ui/widget-actions/#custom-action) in any widget, and clicking in the 'Show help' question mark symbol.

Other tool, is going straight to the api method definition in the [http folder](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/blob/master/ui-ngx/src/app/core/http/attribute.service.ts)

Furthermore, the Javascript APIs are just wrapper of the HTTP REST requests from the UI to the BACKEND, so exploring the swagger of the platform would be a good aid for grasp the behavior. [See telemetry-controller for atributes](https://demo.thingsboard.io/swagger-ui/#/telemetry-controller).

Lastly, it helps to explore the widgetContext object and find relations using the developer console.

```
console.log(widgetContext);
var $injector = widgetContext.$scope.$injector;
var entityGroupService = $injector.get(widgetContext.servicesMap.get('entityGroupService'));
console.log(entityGroupService);
```

Cannot provide links for the entityGroupService because is not implemented in the open code in github nor in the demo swagger, but do in the PE swagger.

Hope being of help.